# What is wrong with this bubble sort algorithm I created?

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, bubble-sort

```
int arraySize = 10;
int[] array = new int[30];

public void generateRandomArray() {
    for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (10-1)+1);
    }
}

public void bubbleSort(){
    for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[i+1]) {
        } else if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
            int storeNumber = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = storeNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

In my driver class I have:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataOperations array = new DataOperations();
        array.generateRandomArray();
        array.printArray();
        array.bubbleSort();
        array.printArray();
    }
}
```

Before the bubble sort I get:

```
0-1
1-8
2-1
3-2
4-9
5-1
6-7
7-2
8-5
9-3
```

After the bubble sort I get:

```
0-1
1-1
2-2
3-8
4-1
5-7
6-2
7-5
8-3
9-0
```

I am not exactly sure what is wrong. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bubble sort is `O(n^2)` you need to repeat your inner loop `n` times.

```
for(int j=0;j<arraySize;j++) {
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
    if(array[i]<array[i+1]){
    }else if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
        int storeNumber=array[i];
        array[i]=array[i+1];
        array[i+1]=storeNumber;
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Why exactly is it n^2?

Comment: because you need to have `n*n` compare operations to bubble sort.

Comment: No, i got that but whats the logic behind that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Why does n times n sort it as opposed to n? Their is a reason that bubble sort works when its n*n and logically I want to know why

Answer (score 0):

The bubble sort you have implemented is wrong.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    for(int j = arraySize-1; j > i; j--) {
         if(A[j] < A[j-1]){
              swap(A[j],A[j-1]);
          }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, its not wrong, the implementation was fine, just not the number of loops ByeBye got it right.

Comment: If you see what he has implemented and what I have is actually same. He has just modified your code and I have tried to give a cleaner implementation of the algorithm. When i say the implementation , I meant the same.

Comment: Oh got it, also I had noticed that your implementation you have arraySize-1, whereas, ByeBye does not any particular reason?

Comment: See because arrays have indexes from 0 to arraySize-1. Technically, @ByeBye also is looping from 0 to arraySize-1. I am just looping reverse. Though not much important, but I am getting the loop of j till i only because array before i will already be sorted.